# Are all functions in a view's column set executed, even if they aren't explicitly referenced in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, user-defined-functions

Assume I have a view definition such as:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
AS
SELECT col1
       , col2
       , dbo.Function(col3) AS col3
  FROM table1
```

Now assume I make the following query:

```
SELECT col1
  FROM view1
```

Will the function be executed in this case, since it is not being referenced in the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have your experiments shown you? What did the execution plan suggest?

Comment: The optimizer should be *capable* of determining that executing the function is not required. Whether it does or not may depend on the specific version of the product (down to patch levels), data volumes, phase of the moon, etc. If you want to know what the optimizer *has* done, you need to ask for the execution plan.

Comment: Maybe; views don't fix anything so the query should be re-written and re-planned as part of its execution (ie the optimizer will take your query on the view and push everything down so it's as if you're running the query that is coded inside the view instead, with fewer columns), and I think it highly likely that the resulting query that runs won't have any reference to the function

Comment: Slight detour....but if you have a scalar function as column value you should consider fixing that regardless.

Comment: Larnu - good call - the execution plan indicates that the function is not called if the column is not referenced.  Should've thought of that first!

Comment: Sean Lange - I'm curious about your reasons for that statement.  It seems reasonable to me that, if you have logic that would be shared across several procedures or views, you might want to encapsulate it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Larnu's suggestion to check the execution plan, I have determined that in at least the case I outlined above, the function is not executed if the column is not referenced.